# Getting a null pointer exception

Tags: apex, exception, null-pointer, null

I was trying to fix a null pointer exception here

```
if(com.Employee__c != null && (mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) == null || (mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) != null && mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c > com.Revenue_Contract_Start_Date__c)))
```

as `mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c`

was null here so replaced this block with

```
if(com.Employee__c != null && (mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) == null ||
                            (mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) != null && ((mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c == null) || (
                                mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c!=null && mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c > com.Revenue_Contract_Start_Date__c)))))
```

But I am still getting the Null Pointer exception at this line `(mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c == null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map.containsKey always returns a **true** or **false** value, but never a **null** value. As such:

> ```
> mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) == null 
>
> (true or false) == null
>
> ((always false!))
> ```

And

> ```
> mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c) != null
>
> (true or false) != null
>
> ((always true!))
> ```

And therefore will keep on going through the shortcut AND operator. True or false will never be null, so the first will never pass, and the latter will never fail.

This means that:

> ```
> mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c).Employee_End_Date__c
> ```

will throw a NullPointerException if `mapEmployees.containskey(com.Employee__c)` returned **false** (because the `== null` will change this to **true**, and the code keeps going when it shouldn't).

By the way, this really over-the-top logic checking, you usually only care of the value itself was null. The following should suffice:

```
User employee = mapEmployees.get(com.Employee__c);
if(employee != null && (
    employee.Employee_End_Date__c == null || 
    employee.Revenue_Contract_Start_Date__c == null || 
    employee.Employee_End_Date__c > employee.Revenue_Contract_Start_Date__c)) {
```

I'm not entirely sure your logic is correct, so this is my best attempt at trying to decipher what you're trying to do, but you can see that simply extracting the map value to a temporary variable has drastically reduced the complexity of your code and makes it easier to understand. This code is also 100% NullPointerException-proof as written.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox This helped me understand the problem with my code.